# I have a problem related to installing vivaldi

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install vivaldi.

I downloaded a .deb file of vivaldi, and i tried to install it with Ubuntu Software Center.

But, I could not install it because the Software Center just shows me the program I installed most recently.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and go to the directory where you have the .deb file, and install it from there; using this command (change the [vivaldifile.dep] to the actual name of .deb file you have):

```
sudo dpkg -i [vivaldifile.dep]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I rebooted before, and I solved the problem, but, I think your saying was the best way to solve the problem. Sorry to don't use the way you said. Sorry. But I'll use the way and it will be the best way. Sorry.